# Class requiring itself as pointer variable, cannot allocate memory

Tags: c++

Im trying to link one display to another display using c++. For instance

```
void funcA(){
Display greenScreen; 
Display redScreen;

greenScreen.setChild(redScreen); 
}
```

Here's the class implementation:

```
class display{
public:
display* child = nullptr; 
void setChild(display);
}
```

Implementation of setChild:

```
void setChild(display childnode){
child = &childnode; 
}
```

I thought this would work, but when i tried to retrieve greenScreen's child, my app crashed. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Helpful reading: [What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419)

Answer (score 0):

This is passing `childnode` *by value*: a copy is made, and you're setting `this->child` to the address of the copy. But the copy only lives while `setChild` is executing, so when it returns, you're left with a dangling pointer, causing undefined behaviour (probably crashing).

You must pass the address of `childnode` instead:

```
void setChild(display *childnode){
child = childnode; 
}
```

Comment: Why not pass a display be reference and take its address internally. Prevents you accidentally setting it to null. Add an explicit function for decoupling displays.

Comment: @MartinYork That's also possible, but a bit unconventional in my experience. Using a pointer has the advantage that you can see at the call site that a pointer is being passed, not a value.

Comment: @Thomas But it also has a disadvantage that it is not clear whether a null pointer can be passed of not.

Comment: Hi guys, thank you so much for answering, i am sad to have overlook this detail. I have posted another thread on regards to gathering more opmitized solution for this problem. Do check out if you guys are interested! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68268828/how-would-you-program-the-logic-of-gui